# How do you post a picture to this site?

Tags: discussion

A request has been made for me to post a picture to this site so as to better understand the problem that I am having.

So, how do I post a picture to this site?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not sure how to state the question or what tag to use.